# Can't edit Excel documents in SharePoint 2010 using the webapp - but it is fine using the Excel Client Application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, excel-services, office-web-apps

I have a SharePoint site where I can edit excel documents using **both** the SharePoint web app and the excel application installed on my PC.

However, in a new site, I can edit the same excel files using the client application, **but not the webapp**.

The error that shows up when I click on "Edit in Browser" option is:

"*You do not have sufficient permissions to edit this workbook*" (see image below)

[image]

I think the message is bit misleading as I still can edit them if I click on "Open in Excel" and check the "Edit" option (see image below)

[image]

Am I missing a configuration in this new site from my user?

Comment: Is that document checked out? Can you try with a different document?

Comment: @AmalHashim  I just created an excel document, uploaded it to the list and tried to edit in browser and got the same error.